# How to install Windows 10 on Ubuntu 18.04 operating system?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

Currently I use ubuntu 18.04 as main operating system. and I need to install windows 10. I don't want to format my ubuntu. Because I usually do my work in ubuntu.

Comment: It's possible to install ubuntu on windows 10. But I want to know how to install windows 10 on ubuntu.

Comment: You can get a new drive, install Windows to it and then add Ubuntu to it off the existing drive.

Comment: Use a Virtual Machine for Windows 10 instead of dual-booting. If you reject reformat-related options, then that's your only choice remaining.

Comment: If UEFI, just let Windows install to unallocated space. It wants lots of partitions and should install its boot loader files into an existing ESP - efi system partition. Be sure to have good backups. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Answer (score 0):

We usually do the inverse, installed Ten and then Ubuntu with Grub. On Ryzen 2700U, Ubuntu 19.04 takes 2.5 minutes to install and Ten, less then 6 minutes.

Comment: I have a ton of downloaded program and system configuration. So I want reverse.

Comment: You should have all that backed up anyway. User settings are all in /home, if system settings those will be in /etc. And you should be backing up list of installed apps if more than a very few. http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools

Comment: Then get an SSD caddy for 20$ and clean install Ten via its USB wire. No need to play with Grub.